# What's the best practice for storing and importing (non-user) data for an iOS app in swift/swiftUI/Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, csv

this is probably a simple question for someone who knows what they're doing, thanks in advance for any pointers for this novice...

I'm learning to use Swift/UI and trying to write a simple app for language learning including verb endings. I have the bare bones app working fine with some sample data that I hard coded. However, to get it working I need to get a lot more data in. This is not user data, but simply a database of words with relationships.

I've set this up in spreadsheets with, e.g., a table for verb categories and a table for verbs. I saved these in csv, dragged and dropped them into the file hierarchy in the sidebar in xcode and used the CodableCSV package to read them and then when the app starts, it assembles them into custom structs that model the data (struct Verb, struct VerbCategory, etc).

That worked ok, but I don't know if it's the best way to do it. However, I now need to introduce a text field/column with commas, line breaks etc. to one of my data files. In case it makes it clearer let me explain one example: for verb categories ('regular verbs'), a 'introduction' column that will contain an explanation of the category. However I try to escape the commas and line breaks it's crashing CodableCSV and I haven't yet had a response from the developer. So I'm thinking of doing it another way.

A spreadsheet is definitely the best way to input the data (c. 1,000 records) because a lot of groups of lines share basic data in common, so they can be copied and tweaked. If I had an easy way to edit json, I suppose it would still be more complex in terms of practically entering the data.

So that's the question: in the abstract, for this kind of task, where the data is not related to the user but is basic data the app needs to initialise, and where it has this kind of structure, how would you build it, how would you get it in the app?

Thanks again!

Comment: If the data is not going to change *during app use* take a look at SQLite. If it *is* going to change, take a look at CoreData

Comment: "What is the best practice" kind of question is opinion-based and that means offtopic. There are many ways to do what you want and depending on your exact needs different ways can be used and usually it's hard to compare which is better. All of them have their pros and cons.

Comment: @Sulthan, true and I like to think outside the box as they say. But then on the other hand, one doesn't want to have to reinvent the wheel, as they also say!

Comment: Follow up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71964834/best-way-to-work-with-a-small-db-in-swift-ios-app-from-a-performance-point-of-vi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "it depends" but you said "a database of words with relationships" - that sounds like a SQLite database in the app bundle would be one option?  It would be easy to create and edit using existing tools like python to export from spreadsheets. It's easy to use in iOS with libraries like SQLite.swift, or GRDB or SwiftData.

It also forms the start of other app features, if you go on to use SQLite to record e.g. the user's progress

Comment: Thanks, so the workflow would be: 1. set up spreadsheet, 2. parse with python and export to sql lite, 3. put SQLite db in the bundle, 4. use appropriate swift libraries to access it.

Comment: I like the idea of using the db for storing user info (it would be keeping a record of what's been learned at this stage), but would mixing user and app data present any problems?

Comment: Yes, or use a sql editor directly to input your data, whatever you like.  One technique would be to copy the database to somewhere else, before editing it with other data (use it as a template)  Or use a different sqlite file for the user progress.

Comment: Using it as a template makes more sense if it the initial data in the db is editable after the initial install rather than just adding to some other table.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Looking into SQLite now and I think this will be the way to go. In this particular case the nature of the data means it will be much easier in a spreadsheet and worth setting up the python to parse it. For example, in one table I have rows for parts of verbs including person, number, tense etc and they change in a regular sequence as I go down the table.

Comment: I don't have enough XP to vote 'useful', but I would do so if I did, perhaps someone else can do that for me!